# At least one non-null i..... as a @Bean when using @EnableWebSecurity. Hint try extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here is what I could not figure out after spending hours try to solve it. I am studying about spring security with java configuration. I came up with the following exception but has no clue what I am supposed to do.

```
  Oct 22, 2015 6:00:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one non-null instance of WebSecurityConfigurer must be exposed as a @Bean when using @EnableWebSecurity. Hint try extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one non-null instance of WebSecurityConfigurer must be exposed as a @Bean when using @EnableWebSecurity. Hint try extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
... 33 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one non-null instance of WebSecurityConfigurer must be exposed as a @Bean when using @EnableWebSecurity. Hint try extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c09b217.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c09b217$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7b0370bc.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
```

The security configuration is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/allmessages*").hasAnyRole("USER", "ANONYMOUS")
                .antMatchers("/postmessages*").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/deletemessages*").hasRole("ADMIM")
            .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("tadtdab").password("tadtab").authorities("ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER")
                .and().withUser("tadi").password("tadi").authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and just after reading this post i found the answer : it's in the stacktrace : if you go to the end of the message, you can find this :

```
Hint try extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

So i just found my webSecurityConfig class and added

```
extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

And my server started correctly